Como asignar valor a una variable pre establecida en IBM Watson Assistant
quiero que cuando inicie mi sistema y habrá el chatbot de Watson, que mi variable user_name, ya tenga el nombre del usuario que se ha logueado.
    onLoad: async (instance) => {

       /*Aqui ya obtengo el nombre desde el html y si va bien*/
        let userName = document.getElementById("user_name").value || '';
        instance.restartConversation();
        instance.updateHomeScreenConfig({
            is_on: true,
            greeting: `Hola ${userName}! Soy tu asistente virtual, dime algo y te ayudo!`
        });
        instance.send({
            input: {
                text: ""
            },
            context: {
                global: {
                    system: {
                        /*Aqui es el problema, no se si estara bien*/
                        user_name: userName
                    }
                }
            }
        }).then((eve) => {
            console.log("Nombre del usuario enviado al contexto:", userName);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error("Error al enviar el nombre al contexto:", err);
        });


        await instance.render();
    }

Si me muestra bien el saludo, pero quiero que mi variable se actualice su valor, ya cree la variable en Watson, además tengo una intención que me dice cuál es mi nombre.
